# Get the fastest answer from multiple thread call

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, mutex, future

I’m working on remote user management with radius, ldap and stuff in c++, I wanted to make the best use of the multiple servers that someone would configure in our program and take the fastest answer from them using multithreading.

So let’s consider some assertion first : we expect the answer of both servers to be the same so we don’t have to check the answer of the slower connection, we can take the first answer and discard the others.

To work on this let’s consider the following function:

```
struct Server;
auto call_server(Server server) -> int;
```

This function call depends on the server connection and block thread execution, a timeout is handled in it, let’s say 10s, we can stub it like this.

```
constexpr int min_sleeping_value = 1'000;
constexpr int max_sleeping_value = 11'000;
constexpr int timeout = max_sleeping_value - 1'000;

struct Server { int result; };
auto get_random_sleeping_time() -> int
{
    static auto rd = std::random_device{};
    static auto distribution = std::uniform_int_distribution{min_sleeping_value, max_sleeping_value};
    static auto mutex = std::mutex{};
    auto lock = std::unique_lock{mutex};
    return distribution(rd);
}

auto call_server(Server server) -> int
{
    auto sleeping_time = get_random_sleeping_time();
    if (sleeping_time > timeout)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{timeout});
        throw std::runtime_error{"timeout"};
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{sleeping_time});
    return server.result;
}
```

In this case, I put the result in the Server struct so you can tell which one respond first, the final implementation expect the same result for all servers call, or at least the server that are actually answering.

So I want to call this function multiple times in parallel and take the first one to answer only.
If all the servers timed out, I want to throw the last exception given by these calls but `std::future` is not meant to be used like this. Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

So I came to this solution, first I declared a structure that contains all of what I need for all the threads:

```
struct async_call_server_params
{
    std::condition_variable cv{};             // for sync with main thread
    std::mutex mutex{};                       // to block before accessing any data
    std::optional<int> result = std::nullopt; // the result
    std::exception_ptr pException = nullptr;  // the exception in case of timeout
    size_t thread_counter = 0;                // a thread counter counting the threads that stopped execution
};
```

Then I wrote an async function of `call_server` wich take the result and put it in the struct (stored in heap with an `std::shared_ptr` to securely write and keep data as long as there’s a thread running). In this simple example, main is terminating right after getting the data but in my program, it keeps running so I need to handle this properly.

```
auto async_call_server(std::weak_ptr<async_call_server_params> weak_params, Server server)
{
    std::optional<int> result = std::nullopt;
    std::exception_ptr pException = nullptr;
    try
    {
        result = call_server(server);
        std::cout << "found result " << *result << '\n';
        
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        pException = std::current_exception();
        std::cerr << "time out for server " << server.result << '\n';
    }
    auto params = weak_params.lock();
    if (params)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock{params->mutex};
        if(!params->result && result)
        {
            params->result = result;
        }
        else if (pException)
        {
            params->pException = pException;
        }

        params->thread_counter += 1;
        params->cv.notify_all();
    }
}
```

Then the main thread calling this:

```
constexpr int nbOfServers = 10;
auto main(int, char*[]) -> int
{
    auto params = std::make_shared<async_call_server_params>();
    auto lock = std::unique_lock{params->mutex};
    for (auto i = 0; i < nbOfServers; i++)
    {
        std::thread{async_call_server, params, Server{i}}.detach();
    }
    params->cv.wait(lock, [&params]{ return params->result || (params->thread_counter == nbOfServers); });
    if (params->result)
    {
        std::cout << "first result: " << *params->result << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        assert(params->pException);
        std::rethrow_exception(params->pException);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I’m mixed up with this solution. I think I came to an elegant way to handle this but I’m suspicious if there’s a way I could use an `std::future` or any more cannonical to achieve this instead.
If you have any idea to achieve this.

If you want to play with this code, feel free to do so: https://godbolt.org/z/dh4xxs53o
You can adjust the number of threads running, the timeout and min and max sleeping time values to simulate all servers timeout.